# Extracting C Function's Parameters Using C++ Metaprogramming (Example from "Practical C++ Metaprogramming")

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming

The following is an example from "Practical C++ Metaprogramming" (pages 16/17):

```
#include <tuple>
#include <typeinfo>

template <typename F>
struct make_tuple_of_params;

template <typename Ret, typename... Args>
struct make_tuple_of_params<Ret (Args...)>
{
   using type = std::tuple<Args...>;
};

template <typename F>
using make_tuple_of_params_t = typename make_tuple_of_params<F>::type;

template<typename F>
void some_magic_function(F f)
{
   // if F is in the form void(double*, double*)
   // make_tuple_of_params is std::tuple<double*, double*>
   make_tuple_of_params_t<F> params;

   // ...
}

void Foo(double* x, double* y) { }

int main()
{
   some_magic_function(Foo);
}
```

It's failing to compile:

```
$ clang++ -std=c++14 MakeTuple.cpp
MakeTuple.cpp:14:5: error: implicit instantiation of undefined template 'make_tuple_of_params<void (*)(double *, double*)>'
```

Is this because the non specialized version of make_tuple_of_params (lines 4 and 5 of the code above) is not defined?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You actually need to different overloading, depending if you extracting it from a pointer or from a signature template argument, see below.

```
template <typename F>
struct make_tuple_of_params;

template <typename Ret, typename... Args>
struct make_tuple_of_params<Ret (*)(Args...)> {
  using type = std::tuple<Args...>;
};

template <typename Ret, typename... Args>
struct make_tuple_of_params<Ret(Args...)> {
  using type = std::tuple<Args...>;
};

template <typename F>
using make_tuple_of_params_t = typename make_tuple_of_params<F>::type;

template <typename F>
bool some_magic_function(F f) {
  // if F is in the form void(double*, double*)
  // make_tuple_of_params is std::tuple<double*, double*>
  return std::is_same<std::tuple<double*, double*>, make_tuple_of_params_t<F>>::value;
}

void Foo(double* x, double* y) {}

int main() {
  cerr << some_magic_function(Foo) << endl;
  cerr
    << std::is_same<std::tuple<int, int>, make_tuple_of_params_t<void(int, int)>>::value
    << endl;
  // The latter one might be handy in some of template metaprogramming constructs
  return 0;
}
```

Sorry, have not look at the book pages, so do not know what the authro meant there.

Comment: Thank you - appreciate your answer.

Comment: @Terence D: Years later but just to clarify his point, "make_tuple_of_params" in your post is specialized on a raw function type, not a pointer to function type which is what you're passing via "Foo" (hence "Yuki" added a specialization taking a function pointer to handle it). There are actually many permutations of specializations to capture all possibilities, assuming you ever needed any others. See my own complete and fully documented (free) solution here: https://github.com/HexadigmAdmin/FunctionTraits (you can review the code itself for learning purposes if req'd or just use it as-is).